# build-pysnmp-mib: convert cisco mib files to a python fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to convert some .my files from the cisco site to .py files to use with pysnmp application but each one is failing.

ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/supportlists/wlc/wlc-supportlist.html

I have already set my SMIPATH to the current directory with all my mibs. But i'm receiving the same error on each of the cisco mibs.

```
root@testbox:/home/johnny# build-pysnmp-mib -o CISCO-CDP-MIB.py CISCO-CDP-MIB.my
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Empty input
smidump -k -f python CISCO-CDP-MIB.my | /usr/bin/libsmi2pysnmp fails
make sure you are using libsmi version > 0.4.5 (or svn)

root@testbox:/home/johnny# build-pysnmp-mib -o CISCO-LWAPP-AAA-MIB.py CISCO-LWAPP-AAA-MIB.my
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Empty input
smidump -k -f python CISCO-LWAPP-AAA-MIB.my | /usr/bin/libsmi2pysnmp fails
make sure you are using libsmi version > 0.4.5 (or svn)
```

Comment: How about "make sure you are using libsmi version > 0.4.5"?

Comment: If it were that simple I would have already fixed it. This is latest pysnmp package

Answer (score 1):

The build-pysnmp-mib script is obsolete since pysnmp 4.3. Please use mibdump.py tool (version 0.0.7 and up) from the [pysmi](http://pysmi.sourceforge.net) package to produce pysnmp MIB modules. You could use produced modules with any pysnmp version.

The following fetched CISCO-LWAPP-MFP-MIB from http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/ and compiled it into pysnmp form along with all other MIBs it depends on:

```
$ mibdump.py CISCO-LWAPP-MFP-MIB
Source MIB repositories: file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs, http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@
MIBs to compile: CISCO-LWAPP-MFP-MIB
Destination format: pysnmp
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes

Created/updated MIBs: CISCO-LWAPP-AP-MIB, CISCO-LWAPP-DOT11-CLIENT-MIB, CISCO-LWAPP-DOT11-MIB, CISCO-LWAPP-MFP-MIB, CISCO-LWAPP-TC-MIB, CISCO-LWAPP-WLAN-MIB, CISCO-SMI, CISCO-TC, CISCO-VTP-MIB, ENTITY-MIB, RMON-MIB
```

You could pass mibdump.py URL(s) for authentic Cisco MIBs repository so it would fetch possibly more recent MIBs directly from there.

Alternatively, if you upgrade pysnmp to version 4.3, you would not need explicit MIB conversion -- it would be all done behind the scenes by pysnmp. Including ASN.1 MIB files search and download from the Internet.

Former (libsmi-based) conversion process is very fragile and buggy.

Comment: I tried using mibdump.py but getting errors with that as well. I'm thinking i'm going to abandon python and use something else

Comment: It is not very probable that pysmi is seriously buggy. But sometimes MIBs are. If you are willing to get you issue resolved, I'd need more details on the failure.

Comment: Added some more detail above. MIBDump.py is displaying errors on every MIB I try

Comment: Alright, that was a bug in pysmi. It is fixed in release 0.0.7 and I am able to convert those CISCO MIBs with mibdump.py. Please try it out and let me know in case of further troubles (https://pypi.python.org/pypi).