# Convert mib to pysnmp on Windows

Tags: mib, pysnmp

I need to convert a MIB to a pysnmp on Windows for use in my SMTP monitoring tool.  But I am a newbie and have no idea where to begin.  I installed Python and ran setup.py install on the pysnmp-master download and it worked fine.  But I am unable to proceed.  I cannot find the script called build-pysnmp-mib which I thought was part of this package.

I would appreciate any pointers in getting me going to I can convert my MIBs to pysnmp on Windows.

Thx!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204995/build-pysnmp-mib-convert-cisco-mib-files-to-a-python-fails-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Did you mean "SNMP monitoring tool"? SMTP is a different and unrelated protocol.